# Unlimited custom fields WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I create unlimited custom fields for WordPress?

I want to create download box, and I don't know user have how many parts.

```
$file1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '1', true);
$file2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '2', true);
$file3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '3', true);
$file4 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '4', true);
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, consider to use ACF plugin.

And you could achieve this by creating **repeat** field and by setting and updating these fields in this way

```
$array_of_parts = get_fied('your-field-name', $post->ID);
```

Or

```
$array_of_parts[] = 'your-new-part';
update_field('your-field-name', $array_of_parts, $post->ID);
```

then you could iterate through these parts with foreach and getting the number of parts by calling

```
count( $array_of_parts )
```

Or use a loop

```
for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++){
    $file = get_post_meta($post->ID, $i, true);
    if(!empty($file)){
        echo $file;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```